# Python - How to perform log2 normalisation only on selected range of rows and cols only

Tags: python, pandas, normalization

I want to perform log2 transformation only on int data type in dataframe without loosing (string) labels in 1st column and row

[image: here is my dataframe]

In excel it looks like this after conversion

[image: log2 normalised]

Please suggest me how to code in python as I am getting error using simple np.log2() transformation due to presence of string

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data1 = pd.read_excel("#here i mention Path Of ExcelFile")
data2 = np.log2(data1)
```

error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'log2'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think first column in excel should be converted to index for only numeric columns:

```
data1 = pd.read_excel("#here i mention Path Of ExcelFile", index_col=0)
data2 = np.log2(data1)
```